# reading an image file in linux using php

Tags: php, linux

I have created an image file like this

```
$imageData = file_get_contents($_POST['imgs1']);
chmod('/var/www/r1/assets/admin/pages/chart/image2.png',0644);
file_put_contents('/var/www/r1/assets/admin/pages/chart/image2.png',$imageData);
```

Now the problem is file is created with lock symbol. How can I remove this lock symbol from file using php?

Comment: what is image data, a binary (octet) stream, a base64 string? It seems strange that image data is being retrieved from `$_POST` rather than `$_FILES`

Comment: this is the url I am trying open and saving. http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=lc&chs=900x300&chdlp=r&chdl=Date%7CSMR%2020%2FSICOM20&chco=3399CC%2C80C65A&chxt=y&chxr=0%2C1%2C37.8&chd=e%3AAABvDeKbMKWm%2C..z.qbLeTpFk

Comment: oh, its a url, i understand now. ok, what is "lock symbol"? I actually have no idea what you are referring to there

Comment: yes,A lock symbol on image when I see the image in my drive.Is it related with ownership or some other issues ?

Comment: try a `chmod()` on the file.

Comment: use exec("chmod -R 777/var/www/r1/assets/admin/pages/chart/image2.png");

Comment: thanks.this changed lock symbol in local.Can I use in live server ? any security issue for using this ?

Answer (score 0):

The lock symbol in Linux is because you don`t have write permission to the file. in this case,file permission is 644 and the owner is user apache.then you don`t have write permission.

For removing the lock icon, change the permission to 755 or change the owner of the file to your user (I recommend changing **chmod**).

```
chmod('/var/www/r1/assets/admin/pages/chart/image2.png',0755);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lock symbol means you don't have permission on that image.To remove lock symbol you have to give right permission 777

use

```
exec("chmod -R 777 /var/www/r1/assets/admin/pages/chart/image2.png");
```